# SDL_CreateRGBSurface using OpenGL texture produces black texture

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl

I'm trying to create a texture with `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` and `SDL_FillRect` functions,
but sadly I'm failing to do so; all I get is a black rectangle.

To achieve that task I'm using following pieces of code (which are working for loading textures from file with `IMG_Load`):

```
#if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN
        rmask = 0xff000000;
        gmask = 0x00ff0000;
        bmask = 0x0000ff00;
        amask = 0x000000ff;
#else
        rmask = 0x000000ff;
        gmask = 0x0000ff00;
        bmask = 0x00ff0000;
        amask = 0xff000000;
#endif
        rect = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE, _w,_h,24,rmask,gmask,bmask,amask);
        if(rect == NULL ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "CreateRGBSurface failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            exit(1);
        }

        Uint32 color = SDL_MapRGBA(rect->format,255,255,0,126);
        SDL_FillRect(rect,NULL,color);
        render.load(rect);
```

with following code sitting in texture loading

```
void Texture::load(SDL_Surface* surface){
    ogl_check_error("surface load");
    GLenum texture_format;
    GLint  nOfColors;
    if (  surface  ) { 

        // get the number of channels in the SDL surface
        nOfColors = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;

        if (nOfColors == 4)     // contains an alpha channel
        {
                if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
                        texture_format = GL_RGBA;
                else
                        texture_format = GL_BGRA;
        } else if (nOfColors == 3){    // no alpha channel

            if (surface->format->Rmask == 0x000000ff)
                    texture_format = GL_RGB;
            else
                    texture_format = GL_BGR;
         }else {
            cerr<<"bad surface"<<endl;
            exit(1);
            }

    // Have OpenGL generate a texture object handle for us
    glGenTextures( 1, &texture );

    // Bind the texture object
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture );

    // Set the texture's stretching properties
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

    // Edit the texture object's image data using the information SDL_Surface gives us
    glTexImage2D( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, nOfColors, surface->w, surface->h, 0,
                    texture_format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, surface->pixels );
} 
else {
    printf("SDL could not load image.bmp: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
    SDL_Quit();
    exit(1);
}    
ogl_check_error("after surface load");
width = surface->w;
height = surface -> h;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the future generations - i've set wrong depth for the rect it should've been 32 instead of 24... .

Answer (score 0):

are you setting the sdl_gl_attributes?

like
          SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
         SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BUFFER_SIZE, 8);